# Line Continuation Spring SQL ScriptUtils (Using H2)

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbc, h2

I have the following SQL script (initDB.sql)

```
CREATE TABLE  FFShareHistorical  (  ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                    PX_LAST  Double DEFAULT NULL, 
                                    PX_OPEN  Double DEFAULT NULL, 
                                    PX_HIGH  Double DEFAULT NULL, 
                                    PX_LOW  Double DEFAULT NULL, 
                                    PRIMARY KEY (ID))
```

and would like to execute it using Spring's ScriptUtils (4.1.4.RELEASE), i.e.

```
Resource rc = new ClassPathResource("initDB.sql");
ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(dataSource.getConnection(), rc);
```

The problem is that it looks like the line breaks are interpreted as termination of the SQL statement, i.e. the error stack trace looks like this

```
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement at line 1 of resource class path resource [initDB.sql]: CREATE TABLE FFShareHistorical ( ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE FFSHAREHISTORICAL ( ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE FFShareHistorical ( ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  [42001-176]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:344)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:204)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readColumnIdentifier(Parser.java:3068)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreateTable(Parser.java:5722)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreate(Parser.java:4122)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:351)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:306)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:278)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:243)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:442)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.process(TcpServerThread.java:265)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:160)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:475)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:393)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:372)
    at ch.qpmlib.flatfiledatabase.jdbc.dao.FFDBSetup.setupDB(FFDBSetup.java:26)
    at ch.qpmlib.flatfiledatabase.jdbc.main.SpringMain.setupDB(SpringMain.java:30)
    at ch.qpmlib.flatfiledatabase.jdbc.main.SpringMain.main(SpringMain.java:17)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE FFSHAREHISTORICAL ( ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE FFShareHistorical ( ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  [42001-176]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:344)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:204)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readColumnIdentifier(Parser.java:3068)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreateTable(Parser.java:5722)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreate(Parser.java:4122)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:351)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:306)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:278)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:243)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:442)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.process(TcpServerThread.java:265)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:160)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

So the question is, how can I use ScriptUtils with a multiline SQL script? Especially I am looking for some kind of "line continuation" character I can add to the script or a way to tell Spring's ScriptUtils to remove all the newline characters.

Comment: I am using 4.1.4.  RELEASE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your archive has documentation. Look at the following locations:

- *spring-framework-4.1.4.RELEASE-dist/spring-framework-4.1.4.RELEASE/docs/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/init/*
- *spring-framework-4.1.4.RELEASE-dist/spring-framework-4.1.4.RELEASE/docs/spring-framework-reference/*

`executeSqlScript(...)` method in internally use a `ResourceDatabasePopulator` 
for executing SQL scripts.

`ResourceDatabasePopulator` provides a simple object-based API for programmatically populating, initializing, or cleaning up a database using SQL scripts defined in external resources.

`ResourceDatabasePopulator` provides options for configuring -

- the character encoding
- statement separator
- comment delimiters
- error handling flags used when parsing and executing the scripts

Each of the configuration options has a *default value*.

Default statement separator within SQL scripts is set to `";"`.

Also:

- `static void executeSqlScript(Connection connection, EncodedResource resource)`
  Execute the given SQL script using default settings for statement separators, comment delimiters, and exception handling flags.
- `static void executeSqlScript(Connection connection, EncodedResource resource, boolean continueOnError, boolean ignoreFailedDrops, String commentPrefix, String separator, String blockCommentStartDelimiter, String blockCommentEndDelimiter)`
  Execute the given SQL script.
- `static void executeSqlScript(Connection connection, Resource resource)`
  Execute the given SQL script using default settings for statement separators, comment delimiters, and exception handling flags.

---

However, there are fallback mechanism to `"\n"` when there is no `";"` in the entire script. See @chuchikaeschtli answer for more details.

Comment: I appreciate the effort and upvoted it. However, it does not really answer the question, i.e. the problem is the fallback mechanism to "\n" when there is no ";" in the entire script. If you add this to your answer I will accept it. Thx.

Answer (score 8):

As it turns out, there is no problem using a multiline statement. However, if the statement(s) is not terminated by a ";", then ScriptUtils will fall back to using "\n" as a separator. So in this case just terminating the script using a ";" i.e.

```
CREATE TABLE  FFShareHistorical  (  ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                    PX_LAST  Double DEFAULT NULL, 
                                    PX_OPEN  Double DEFAULT NULL, 
                                    PX_HIGH  Double DEFAULT NULL, 
                                    PX_LOW  Double DEFAULT NULL, 
                                    PRIMARY KEY (ID));
```

will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

`ScriptUtils` has explicit support for such scenarios.

Simply pass `ScriptUtils.EOF_STATEMENT_SEPARATOR` as the value for the `separator`.

Here is the Javadoc for `EOF_STATEMENT_SEPARATOR`:

> End of file (EOF) SQL statement separator: "^^^ END OF SCRIPT ^^^".
>
> This value may be supplied as the separator to `executeSqlScript(Connection, EncodedResource, boolean, boolean, String, String, String, String)` to denote that an SQL script contains a single statement (potentially spanning multiple lines) with no explicit statement separator. Note that such a script should not actually contain this value; it is merely a *virtual* statement
>   separator.

Regards,

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)